# Need to create an activity tracker on Google sheets with onEdit script where non-admin can only add timestamp once and won't be able to change it

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

[What we do temporarily](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aQsEN.png)

As of right now, we're just doing it like this.

But what I wanted is that they can use the "Ctrl+Shift+;" function to add timestamp on Start and End column but won't ever be able to change it. I have tried adding permissions but people cannot even add timestamps because they don't have any permissions to edit it at all.

As for the Durations column, I also want to know what's the best function or script to calculate the durations in HH:MM or MM format based on Start and End timestamps.

Wanted it to look like this: (this one doesn't have any script at all)
[What I want it to be shown with script](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7osHF.png)

So, yeah. I want my staff to be able to add timestamps only once then won't be able to change it. Only I may be able to.

Thanks!

I tried format and set permissions but not the answer. Someone in reddit told me I need a script for it.

Comment: I have seen and tried that already when I was working for a different company. It's possible. Unfortunately, there's no way for me to get the script or codes to do it because I'm not the admin or assigned on that google sheet.

Answer (score 0):

Here's an example of a non-scripted approach you might be able to adapt:

- Create a new sheet and enable iterative calculation in settings; set max. no. of iterations to 1.
- In A1 & C1 add tick boxes
- In B1 add the following formula:

```
=if(and(A1,B1=0),now(),B1)
```

- In D1 add the following formula:

```
=if(and(C1,D1=0),now(),D1)
```

- In E1 add the following formula:

```
=if(and(B1<>0,D1<>0),D1-B1,)
```

- Protect columns B/D/E so that only you can edit

Ticking box A1 sets a start time in B1 and ticking C1 an end time in D1 using NOW(). If both are ticked then the difference (i.e. the duration) is calculated in E1. If A1 or C1 is unticked the times in B1 or D1 do not change (as the deliberate circular reference in B1 or D1 only sets the time if B1 or D1 are in their initial state). End users can't delete the formulas in B1, D1 or E1 as they are protected. You will need to set the number format of E1 to 'Duration' otherwise you'll just see a timestamp. B1 & D1 show '0' as their initial state - this can also be dealt with using custom number formats to suppress the zero if required.